# Access an element by class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with an ID of `InstrumentListGrid`.  When a row is selected, it sets the class to `ui-iggrid-activerow`. I want to add a jQuery event on that row for when someone clicks it.

So far I have

```
$("#InstrumentListGrid tr.ui-iggrid-activerow").click(function (event) {
    alert("YAY!");
});
```

but that isn't firing.  How do I bind to an element by class?

Comment: Is the table or class dynamically added?

Comment: The table isn't but the class is dynamically added using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the class is presumably added dynamically you should use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$('#InstrumentListGrid').delegate('.ui-iggrid-activerow', 'click', function (e) {
    // do stuff.
});
```

Comment: +1 `delegate()` is a much better fit than `live()` in this case

Comment: In what cases would `live()` be better than `delegate()`?

Comment: Awesome! `delegate()` needs more champions :)

Comment: @link664: if the container is unknown.  `.delegate()` is essentially just a bounded `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `ui-iggrid-activerow` is dynamically added. Use the `live()` function:

```
$('#InstrumentListGrid tr.ui-iggrid-activerow').live('click', function() {
    alert('YAY!');
});
```